# Is it possible to maintain "boundness" of a method when passing it as an object outside its class

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a library that will register an arbitrary list of service calls from multiple service endpoints to a container.  I intend to implement the service calls in classes written one per service.  Is there a way to maintain the boundedness of the methods from the service classes when registering them to the container (so they will still have access to the instance data of their owning object instance), or must I register the whole object then write some sort of pass through in the container class with `__getattr__` or some such to access the methods within instance context?

container:

```
class ServiceCalls(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._service_calls = {}
    def register_call(self, name, call):
        if name not in self._service_calls:
            self._service_calls[name] = call
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._service_calls:
           return self._service_calls[name]
```

services:

```
class FooSvc(object):
    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self.endpoint = endpoint
    def fooize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #call fooize service call with args/kwargs utilizing self.endpoint
    def fooify(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #call fooify service call with args/kwargs utilizing self.endpoint


class BarSvc(object):
    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self.endpoint = endpoint
    def barize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #call barize service call with args/kwargs utilizing self.endpoint
    def barify(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #call barify service call with args/kwargs utilizing self.endpoint
```

implementation code:

```
foosvc = FooSvc('fooendpoint')
barsvc = BarSvc('barendpoint')
calls = ServiceCalls()
calls.register('fooize', foosvc.fooize)
calls.register('fooify', foosvc.fooify)
calls.register('barize', barsvc.barize)
calls.register('barify', barsvc.barify)
calls.fooize(args)
```

Comment: This question is a bit vague.  Could you include a code example?

Comment: I haven't really written it yet, I was trying to determine if it is even feasible before investing time in it.  I'll try to hack something illustrative together above though...

Comment: @SvenMarnach does that clarify the question a bit?
I was thinking of making each call an object, maybe inited with the overall service data, then having it either be callable or contain a call() method.  Actually, maybe that's the way I'll go, as it will still leave the interface clean for call users and implementers.

Comment: Well, I've added an answer.  If it answers your question, you *did* clarify the post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will work fine, as you can see by running your own code. :)

The object `foosvc.fooize` is called a "bound method" in Python, and it contains both, a reference to `foosvc` and to the function `FooSvc.fooize`.  If you call the bound method, the reference to `self` will be passed implicitly as the first paramater.

On a side note, `__getattr__()` shouldn't silently return `None` for invalid attribute names.  Better use this:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        return self._service_calls[name]
    except KeyError:
        raise AttributeError
```

Comment: Oh, it will work?  I thought I recalled it not working from messing with something similar previously... and yes, my actual code does not fail silently, I just figured that exceptions were extraneous to the actual question at hand.  I could have sworn passing a method out of an instance returned an unbound method... oh well.  :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this answers your question:

```
In [2]: f = 1 .__add__

In [3]: f(3)
Out[3]: 4
```

You won't need the `staticmethod` function when adding these functions to classes, because they are effectively already "staticed".

Comment: Bound methods aren't descriptors themselves, so you won't need `staticmethod`.

Comment: `staticmethod` defeats the purpose though.  The whole idea is to have access to instance data, which by definition, static methods do not.

Comment: @sr2222 That's not how it works. Staticmethod wraps the function passed to it - it doesn't magically alter it to rip out the binding of its first parameter.

Comment: I thought classmethod was the one that still had access to self, not staticmethod.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the use case for this -- it seems to me that the easy, simple, idiomatic way to accomplish this is to just pass in an object.

**But**:  program to the interface, not the implementation.  Only assume that the object has the method you need -- don't touch the internals or any other methods.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm trying to write an interface that is easy to use for both people with only a passing acquaintance with how services work and for people that need to easily extend the service library available.  For the former, the idea is that service.foo() will call the foo service with all the configuration and serialization happening automagically, and for the later, they can easily register new service calls to the interface for the former users to use.  The trick is in structuring the built in calls in an efficient and maintainable way.